# Run `cargo test --workspace` and exclude one test

Tags: testing, rust, rust-cargo, exclude-constraint

I have a workspace with several crates.  I need to exclude a particular test.

I tried adding an environment variable check, but this doesn't work.  I guess `cargo test` filters out the environment variables.

```rust
// package1/src/lib.rs

// ...

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {

    #[test]
    fn test1() {
        if std::env::var("CI").is_ok() {
            return;
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then I tried passing the [`--exclude`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-test.html#package-selection) parameter with various options, but none of them work:

- `cargo test --workspace --exclude test1`
- `cargo test --workspace --exclude tests:test1`
- `cargo test --workspace --exclude tests::test1`
- `cargo test --workspace --exclude '*test1'`
- `cargo test --workspace --exclude 'tests*test1'`
- `cargo test --workspace --exclude package1`
  This skips all of the tests in the package.
- `cargo test --workspace --exclude 'package1*test1'`

How can I run all workspace tests except one?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Excluding a test

The help file by running `cargo test -- --help` lists useful options:

```
--skip FILTER   Skip tests whose names contain FILTER (this flag can
                be used multiple times)
```

Regarding the `--` after `test`, see:

- [What does “--” (double-dash) mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean/187548#187548)

**src/lib.rs**

```rust
fn add(a: u64, b: u64) -> u64 {
    a + b
}

fn mul(a: u64, b: u64) -> u64 {
    a * b
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::{add, mul};

    #[test]
    fn test_add() {
        assert_eq!(add(21, 21), 42);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_mul() {
        assert_eq!(mul(21, 2), 42);
    }
}
```

Runing the above with `cargo test -- --skip test_mul` will give the following output:

```
running 1 test
test tests::test_add ... ok
```

### Excluding a test within a specific package

If you want to exclude a specific test for package within a workspace, you can do so in the following way, replacing `my_package` and `my_test` with their appropriate names:

Test all, but exclude `my_package`

```
cargo test --workspace --exclude my_package
```

And then test `my_package` itself, with the specific test excluded by adding `--skip my_test`:

```
cargo test --package my_package -- --skip my_test
```

For more options, see:

- [The Cargo Book, "cargo-test(1)"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-test.html)

### Excluding a test by default

Alternatively, you could add the `#[ignore]` attribute to tests that should not run by default. You can still run them separately if you wish to do so:

**src/lib.rs**

```rust
#[test]
#[ignore]
fn test_add() {
    assert_eq!(add(21, 21), 42);
}
```

Running the tests using `cargo test -- --ignored`:

```
running 1 test
test tests::test_add ... ok
```

If you're using Rust >= `1.51` and want to run all tests, including those marked with the `#[ignore]` attribute, you can pass `--include-ignored`.

Comment: Is there any way to specify the package or crate name to the `-- --skip` argument?

Comment: @M.Leonhard as far as I'm aware you'll have to split it into two commands. I have updated the post to reflect this.

Comment: Note that `cargo test --workspace -- --skip FILTER` works perfectly fine, if you want to apply the filter to every package.